# Postgresql 12: Evenly distribute data among N partitions

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, data-partitioning

Relevant tables for the following question

```
CREATE TABLE "users" (
    "usersid" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "created_at" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    "updated_at" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    "active" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
    "name" TEXT,
    "discordid" BIGINT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    "rank" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ...
) WITH (OIDS=FALSE);

CREATE TABLE "reactions" (
    "reactionsid" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "created_at" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    "updated_at" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    "active" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
    "discordid" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "channelid" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "messageid" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "reaction" TEXT NOT NULL,
    ...
) WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
```

I'm working on a Discord bot and I'd like to evenly distribute people into groups based on their ranks amongst groups of size 10 (though we may not always reach a group size of 10 for each group).

Suppose I have X ranks of "leaders" and Y ranks of "attendees".
I want to have at least 1 "leader" in every group (if possible) and then evenly distribute the "attendees" based on their ranks amongst each group.

Sample users data:

```
SELECT u.usersid, u.name, u.rank
FROM reactions r
JOIN users u ON (u.discordid = r.discordid)
WHERE r.active AND u.active
  AND r.messageid = 876963120768229376
  AND r.reaction = ''
ORDER BY u.rank DESC;
```

```
 usersid |   name    | rank
---------+-----------+------
       1 | Jim       |   25  -- leader rank
      60 | Tina      |   24  -- leader rank
      59 | Dalton    |   24  -- leader rank
      26 | Jake      |   23  -- leader rank
      47 | Tom       |   22  -- attendee rank
      58 | Kyle      |   22  -- attendee rank
      64 | John      |   21  -- attendee rank
      33 | Zack      |   21  -- attendee rank
      36 | Allen     |   21  -- attendee rank
      15 | Sarah     |   21  -- attendee rank
      13 | Lisa      |   21  -- attendee rank
      39 | Joe       |   21  -- attendee rank
      21 | Allison   |   20  -- attendee rank
      19 | Bob       |   20  -- attendee rank
      77 | Sam       |   17  -- attendee rank
      78 | Cid       |   17  -- attendee rank
      80 | Alice     |   17  -- attendee rank
      82 | Hannah    |   17  -- attendee rank
      89 | Cassandra |   17  -- attendee rank
      91 | Vanessa   |   17  -- attendee rank
      76 | Quinton   |   17  -- attendee rank
```

I want to break this up into a grouping of:
Group 1: Jim, Jake, Tom, John, Zack, Allen, Bob, Sam, Cid, Alice
G1 Rank Sum: 25 + 23 + 22 + 21 + 21 + 21 + 20 + 17 + 17 + 17 = 204
Group 2: Dalton, Tina, Kyle, Sarah, Lisa, Joe, Allison, Hannah, Cassandra, Vanessa, Quinton
G2 Rank Sum: 24 + 24 + 22 + 21 + 21 + 21 + 20 + 17 + 17 + 17 = 204

Some important notes:

- Group sizes being equal should take priority over the rank sum of the
  groups being equal or near equal.
- Not all groups may be able to have a "leader" rank so the next highest "attendee" rank should be used.

I've been exploring windowing functions such as NTILE, but I'm having difficulty working out how to do this. This is where I'm at and it's not right, but it does get me arrays of names which is the goal. They just aren't distributed correctly or evenly.

```
WITH reaction_meta AS (
    SELECT
        r.messageid,
        CEIL(COUNT(1) / 10.0)::INT AS count
    FROM reactions r
    WHERE r.active
      AND r.reaction = ''
    GROUP BY r.messageid
)
SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(x.name)
FROM (
    SELECT
        u.name,
        u.rank,
        NTILE(rm.count) OVER (
            PARTITION BY u.rank
            ORDER BY u.rank
        ) AS bucket,
        r.reactionsid,
        r.discordid,
        r.channelid,
        r.messageid,
        r.reaction
    FROM reactions r
    JOIN reaction_meta rm ON (rm.messageid = r.messageid)
    JOIN users u ON (u.discordid = r.discordid)
    WHERE r.active
      AND r.messageid = 876963120768229376
      AND r.reaction = ''
    ORDER BY u.rank DESC
) x
GROUP BY bucket;
```

Any thoughts or insights would be helpful.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm totally lost.  Your sample data and table descriptions seem to have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: I tried to update the description to provide some more detail. Please let me know if this is still confusing!